# Why can't I define a complex function like this?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's start with the real analytic function $f(x) = {1 \over x^2 + 1}$. Then $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and it's possible to extend that function to a holomorphic one on the complex plane by $f(z) = {1 \over z^2 + 1}$. By the Identity Theorem the extended function has to be unique, but what about: $$f(z)\neq g(z) = g(x+iy) := {\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_n x^n}} + i {\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_n y^n}}$$ Doesn't this function statisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and is therefore holomorphic?

Is there a problem with how I defined $g$ or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, in other words, you want to know if $g(x+iy)=\frac1{1+x^2}+i\frac1{1+y^2}$ is holomorphic? I haven't checked the C-R equations, but I doubt the hold.

Comment: you have just showed $g$ isn't holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you actually try the Cauchy-Riemann conditions on $g$, and decide for yourself whether they are true. (When you do so, please note that $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, and are not interchangable.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,$ where $a_0,a_1,\dots \in \mathbb {R}$ and the series converges for $x \in (-r,r).$ Define

$$f(x+iy) = u(x) +iu(y), x+iy \in (-r,r)\times (-r,r).$$

Then $f'(x+iy)$ exists (in the complex sense) iff $u'(x)=u'(y).$ This follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Notice that this implies $f'(z)$ always exists for every $z$ on the diagonal of $(-r,r)\times (-r,r).$